# set different bg_color for different columns in xlsxwriter python

Tags: python, formatting, xlsx, xlsxwriter

I want to set different background fill colors for different columns, but I'm not getting as expected.

```
import xlsxwriter 

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('Example5.xlsx') 
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet() 
bg_format = workbook.add_format()
colors = ['green', 'cyan', 'magenta']
content = ["A", "B", "C", "D"]
for i in range(5):
    bg_format.set_bg_color(colors[i % 3])
    print(colors[i % 3])
    worksheet.write_column(1, i, content, cell_format=bg_format)
workbook.close()
```

what i am getting is:

[image: the output i am getting]

what i expect to get:

[image: the output i am expecting]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Format in XlsxWriter is "applied to a cell not in its current state but in its final state" (see this [section of the docs](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/format.html#modifying-formats)). So in your example only one unique format is created and that has the last color that was applied.

You can fix this by creating a new format in the loop:

```py
for i in range(5):
    bg_format = workbook.add_format()
    bg_format.set_bg_color(colors[i % 3])
    print(colors[i % 3])
    worksheet.write_column(1, i, content, cell_format=bg_format)
```

However, that can be inefficient for a large number of iterations. A more efficient way would be to create a unique format for each of the color types you need and reuse them. Like this:

```py
import xlsxwriter 

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('Example5.xlsx') 
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet() 

green_format   = workbook.add_format({'bg_color': 'green'})
cyan_format    = workbook.add_format({'bg_color': 'cyan'})
magenta_format = workbook.add_format({'bg_color': 'magenta'})

bg_formats = [green_format, cyan_format, magenta_format]
colors     = ['green', 'cyan', 'magenta']
content    = ["A", "B", "C", "D"]

for i in range(5):
    bg_format = bg_formats[i % 3]
    print(colors[i % 3])
    worksheet.write_column(1, i, content, cell_format=bg_format)

workbook.close()
```

**Output**:

[image]